# Extracting html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from the html of the following site:

> http://www.irishrugby.ie/guinnesspro12/results_and_fixtures_pro_12_section.php

I want to be able to extract the team names and the score for example the first fixture is `Connacht vs Newport Gwent Dragons`.

I want my python program too print the result,  i.e `Connacht Rugby 29 - 23 Newport Gwent Dragons`.

Here is the html I want too extract it from:

```
<!-- 207974 sfms -->
<tr class="odd match-result group_celtic_league" id="fixturerow0" onclick="if( c
lickpriority == 0 ) { redirect('/guinnesspro12/35435.php') }" onmouseout="classN
ame='odd match-result group_celtic_league';" onmouseover="clickpriority=0; class
Name='odd match-result group_celtic_league rollover';" style="">
 <td class="field_DateShort" style="">
  Fri 4 Sep
 </td>
 <td class="field_TimeLong" style="">
  19:30
 </td>
 <td class="field_CompStageAbbrev" style="">
  PRO12
 </td>
 <td class="field_LogoTeamA" style="">
  <img alt="Connacht Rugby" height="50" src="http://cdn.soticservers.net/tools/i
mages/teams/logos/50x50/16.png" width="50"/>
 </td>
 <td class="field_HomeDisplay" style="">
  Connacht Rugby
 </td>
 <td class="field_Score" style="">
  29 - 23
 </td>
 <td class="field_AwayDisplay" style="">
  Newport Gwent Dragons
 </td>
 <td class="field_LogoTeamB" style="">
  <img alt="Newport Gwent Dragons" height="50" src="http://cdn.soticservers.net/
tools/images/teams/logos/50x50/19.png" width="50"/>
 </td>
 <td class="field_HA" style="">
  H
 </td>
 <td class="field_OppositionDisplay" style="">
  <br/>
 </td>
 <td class="field_ResScore" style="">
  W 29-23
 </td>
 <td class="field_VenName" style="">
  Sportsground
 </td>
 <td class="field_BroadcastAttend" style="">
  3,624
 </td>
 <td class="field_Links" style="">
  <a href="/guinnesspro12/35435.php" onclick="clickpriority=1">
   Report
  </a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

This is my program so far:

```
from httplib2 import Http
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# create a "web object"
h = Http()

# Request the specified web page
response, content = h.request('http://www.irishrugby.ie/guinnesspro12/results_and_fixtures_pro_12_section.php')

# display the response status
print(response.status)

# display the text of the web page
print(content.decode())

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

# check the response
if response.status == 200:
    #print(soup.get_text())

    rows = soup.find_all('tr')[1:-2]

    for row in rows:
        data = row.find_all('td')
        #print(data)

else:
    print('Unable to connect:', response.status)
    print(soup.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding all the `<td>` tags you should be more specific.  I would convert this:

```
for row in rows:
    data = row.find_all('td')
```

to this:

```
for row in rows:
    home = row.find("td",attrs={"class":"field_HomeDisplay")
    score = row.find("td",attrs={"class":"field_Score")
    away = row.find("td",attrs={"class":"field_AwayDisplay")
    print(home.get_text() + " " + score.get_text() + " " + away.get_text())
```

Comment: What about do something like `score = home.findNext()`?

Comment: Also this way(not an answer, just for fun): `print(*[i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('td') if i.text.strip() != ''][3:6])`

Comment: @KevinGuan I like the `.findNext()` solution, and the other solution is creative.  I try to be as explicit as possible (sometimes longwinded) in case they throw another `td` in the mix and it breaks everything.  Of course if they change the class names mine will be broken.  However I think the class names are less likely to change than the page layout so that is why I explicitly name them.

Comment: Yeah, just found some interesting solutions. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way: downloading the .ics (calendar file) and parse. The calendar file is just a text file and the format is easier to parse and it is available [here](http://www.irishrugby.ie/tools/calendars/irfu-irfu-guinnesspro12.ics?v=144656). If you look at the top of your original page, you will see a link to download the .ics file.

The code will be really simple since each record in the .ics file looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20151103T141214Z
DTSTART:20150904T183000Z
DTEND:20150904T183000Z
SUMMARY:Connacht Rugby 29 - 23 Newport Gwent Dragons
DESCRIPTION:Competition - Guinness PRO12
LOCATION:Sportsground
URL:/rugby/match_centre.php?section=overview&amp;fixid=207974
UID:20150904T183000ZConnacht Rugby 29 - 23 Newport Gwent Dragons
END:VEVENT
```

All you want is to look for lines that starts with `SUMMARY:` and remove that tag:

```
from httplib2 import Http

def extract_summary(content):
    for line in content.splitlines():
        if line.startswith('SUMMARY:'):
            line = line.replace('SUMMARY:', '')
            yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = Http()
    response, content = h.request('http://www.irishrugby.ie/tools/calendars/irfu-irfu-guinnesspro12.ics?v=144656')
    content = content.decode()
    for line in extract_summary(content):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req_cols = ['field_HomeDisplay', 'field_Score', 'field_AwayDisplay']
html = requests.get('http://www.irishrugby.ie/guinnesspro12/results_and_fixtures_pro_12_section.php')

if html.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text)
    fixtures = soup.find('table', class_='fixtures')

    for row in fixtures.find_all('tr'):
        try:
            print(' '.join(row.find('td', class_=col).get_text() for col in req_cols))
        except:
            pass
```

This would give you the following type of output:

```
Connacht Rugby 29 - 23 Newport Gwent Dragons
Connacht Rugby 29 - 23 Newport Gwent Dragons
Edinburgh Rugby 16 - 9 Leinster Rugby
Ulster Rugby 28 - 6 Ospreys
Munster Rugby 18 - 13 Benetton Treviso
Glasgow Warriors 33 - 32 Connacht Rugby
.
.
.
Connacht Rugby   v   Glasgow Warriors
Leinster Rugby   v   Benetton Treviso
Munster Rugby   v   Scarlets
Ospreys   v   Ulster Rugby
   v   
   v   
   v
```